# Text alignment disturbed after applying "word-break" css property

Tags: html, css, word-wrap, text-alignment, text-align

I have a div and bulk of content loaded into this div. I applied some CSS style for managing the div width: `word-break: break-all; word-wrap: break-word;

but after applying this css the div alignment was disturbed, because I noticed some words are truncating after this.

My css is:

```
width: 98%;
word-break: break-all;
word-wrap: break-word;
text-align: justify;
```

I did't understand how can I get `justify` align text with those css, How can i overcome this problem?
Can any one suggest me to another CSS style to resolve this problem?

[See in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94Kq4/)

Thank you...!![image: Here the image of my div with truncated words at the end]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find-out some CSS style which help me to overcome my problem:

CSS:

```
    width : 440px;
    white-space: pre;           /* CSS 2.0 */
    white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS 2.1 */
    white-space: pre-line;      /* CSS 3.0 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla */
    white-space: -hp-pre-wrap;  /* HP Printers */
    word-wrap: break-word;
    -moz-hyphens:auto; 
    -webkit-hyphens:auto; 
    -o-hyphens:auto; 
    hyphens:auto;
    text-align: justify;
```

Answer (score 1):

Html way of doing the same would be adding `<wbr>` before/after/embedded in your long word

```
wbr:after { content: "\00200B" }
```

for doing it [css](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html) way

Comment: It's works, but if space of the content was remove. Please see this - http://jsfiddle.net/94Kq4/2/

Comment: ok, you wrap a block of text into <wbr> tag and it's works fine, but in my case it's not possible because the content size is too large and data fetch from database.

Comment: add <wbr> to text that you are retrieving else you need to find a different solution, leaving for the day best luck buddy.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the html code

```
<div id="Content">
TestTestTest TestTestTest TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest TestTestTest TestTestTestTest ################################################ TestTestTestTest TestTestTest TestTestTest TestTestTest TestTestTest TestTestTest TestTestTest TestTestTestTest TestTestTest TestTestTestTest TestTestTest TestTestTest TestTestTest TestTestTest TestTestTest TestTestTest TestTestTestTest TestTestTest TestTestTestTest T </div>
```

and here's your fiddle. words dont break here specially the # i used to check. Please see that you do't enter a new line character like pressing enter

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EFSLv/)

Comment: but i want: If content have some spaces, link-break than i need to show it with align text.

Comment: spaces wont matter it will not break. and line breaks will appear exacctly where you want . Give a try in the fiddle but use <br> instead of pressing enter :)